# Return all non connected nodes or nodes those are on degree of more than 2

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to return nodes which are either not connected or connected on degree of 2 or more
For example **a--b--c d e** are the nodes and if i want to return nodes for **a** then result should be **c**,**d**,**e**

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for a given starting node, you want nodes that are 2 or more away, or not connected at all.

Another way to say it is you want all nodes that are not the node in question itself, or connected one degree away from it. This is the easier case to find for the query.

For this example I'll assume that the node in question is named "a". In your actual query, you will want to use labels where appropriate, and have an index or unique constraint on the label/property you plan on using for the lookup. Otherwise, for large graphs, your query may be slow.

```
MATCH (a {name:'a'})-[*0..1]-(excluded)
WITH COLLECT(excluded) as excludedNodes
MATCH (remaining)
WHERE NOT remaining IN excludedNodes
RETURN remaining
```